# Changing Cell Text based on information from another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm creating a list of cards for my friend group. I have a working search bar and formatting to highlight in specific colors based on if the card is restricted in a number of ways. I'm trying to change the text value of that status in my master sheet based on if the card exists in one of my restriction sheets. I've tried various things to no avail.

I've been trying few different nested IF statements with the most recent being =INDEX(IF($B$3:$B$5000,INDIRECT("Banned!"$B$1:$B$5000)"Banned",IF($B$3:$B$5000,INDIRECT("Limit 2!"$B$1:$B$5000)"Limit 2", IF($B$3:$B$5000,INDIRECT("Limit 1!"$B$1:$B$5000)"Limit 1", "No Limit"))))

I have other sheets titled like those in the code and I have a few things in them. I'm attempting to make the code right with "Decode Talker" which I made a copy of the information inside the "Banned" sheet.[Add information to a restriction page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOxJz.png) - [Desired output in my master table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVSdO.png)

The sheet in total if you want to copy and look it over.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q4yK4JatEwKrY5ovh52GH9POhzfWqjEIqVuZJ0pM7r0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try this in `Cell_K3434` for **Decode Talker** listed in `Cell_B3434`:*

```js
=ifs(len(ifna(vlookup(B3434,Banned!B:B,1,))),"Banned",len(ifna(vlookup(B3434,'Limit 1'!B:B,1,))),"Limit 1",len(ifna(vlookup(B3434,'Limit 2'!B:B,1,))),"Limit 2",1,"No Limit")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! That works, now to spend time breaking that apart to understand why lol. Have a great day.